# FactoryConfigurationError thrown when trying to load jar from ByteArray with custom ClassLoader

Tags: java, arrays, classloader, runtimeexception

I want to dynamically load JAR Files using a ClassLoader from a ByteArray. It works fine with every executable JAR Files I've tried it with so far, except a Program using WebLaF. I always get the following set of Errors:

```
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be created
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver.<init>(DomDriver.java:64)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver.<init>(DomDriver.java:56)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver.<init>(DomDriver.java:48)
    at com.alee.utils.XmlUtils.initializeXStream(XmlUtils.java:90)
    at com.alee.utils.XmlUtils.getXStream(XmlUtils.java:77)
    at com.alee.utils.XmlUtils.processAnnotations(XmlUtils.java:141)
    at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel$2.propertyChange(WebLookAndFeel.java:855)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(Unknown Source)
    at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel.install(WebLookAndFeel.java:932)
    at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel.install(WebLookAndFeel.java:918)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at xx.ByteCodeClassLoader.main(ByteCodeClassLoader.java:178)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be created
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory: Error locating configuration files
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot fetch URL out of res
    at xx.ByteCodeClassLoader.findResources(ByteCodeClassLoader.java:72)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.alee.utils.XmlUtils.processAnnotations(XmlUtils.java:141)
    at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel$2.propertyChange(WebLookAndFeel.java:855)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(Unknown Source)
    at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel.install(WebLookAndFeel.java:932)
    at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel.install(WebLookAndFeel.java:918)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at xx.ByteCodeClassLoader.main(ByteCodeClassLoader.java:178)
```

After this, the JAR runs successfully until it has to load the GUI. Then it crashes with another error:

```
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be created
```

My Code is the following:

```
public class ByteCodeClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    final Map<String, byte[]> classes;
    final Map<String, byte[]> res;

    -snip-

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        byte[] code = classes.get(name);
        if (code != null){
            return defineClass(name, code, 0, code.length);
        }
        return super.findClass(name);
    }

    @Override
    public URL getResource(String name) {
        URL ur = ByteCodeClassLoader.class.getResource(name);
        if (ur != null) {
            return ur;
        }
        try {
            return new URL(null, "bytes:///" + name, new BytesHandler());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(res.get(name));
    }

    @Override
    protected Enumeration<URL> findResources(String name) throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("Cannot fetch URL out of res");
    }


   -snip-
```

If you know a solution to this issue, it would help me greatly. Even just a lead in the right direction would be awesome. I hope I supplied all the important information.